# Laravel bad query insert

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a  problem inserting data into my database and always get the following error.

> SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1416 Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

I tried to insert data with my Eloquent model using query builder, but it gave me the same error. In the migration file I have:

```php
Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id')->autoIncrement()->primary();
    $table->text("name");
    $table->multiLineString("opinion");
    $table->string("post");
    $table->timestamp("date");
});
```

I've also tried to insert data with this:

```
$validatedData = $this->validate($request, [
    'name'    => 'required|alpha_dash|max:40|min:3',
    'opinion' => 'required|alpha_dash|max:40|min:3',
]);

$validatedData = Binput::all();

DB::table("books")->insert([
    "name"    => $validatedData["name"],
    "post"    => $url,
    "opinion" => $validatedData["opinion"],
]);
```

Comment: What is the output of `dd($validatedData["opinion"]);`?

Comment: array:3 [▼
  "name" => "string"
  "opinion" => "string"
  "submit" => "string"
]

Comment: opinion is string it was "filali"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this `Binput::all();` came from.

Can you try to delete this line `$validatedData = Binput::all();`

**Should be:**

```
$validatedData = $this->validate($request, [
    'name'    => 'required|alpha_dash|max:40|min:3',
    'opinion' => 'required|alpha_dash|max:40|min:3',
]);

DB::table("books")->insert([
    "name"    => $validatedData["name"],
    "post"    => $url,
    "opinion" => $validatedData["opinion"],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by changing the migration instead of string and text i did char and it work

```
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->autoIncrement()->primary();
            $table->char("name");
            $table->char("opinion");
            $table->char("post");
            $table->timestamps();
```

when i tried this migration it work 
thank you all